# Why is my document-level add-in shutting down when a third-party add-in button is clicked?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I created a simple Excel document-level customization written in C# and when I click "Save as Adobe PDF" in the File menu, the BeforeClose event of my add-in is called (so it's shutting down my add-in). How do I prevent this from happening, as I have no control over what third-party add-ins do?

To troubleshoot, I created a base document-level customization for Excel and I still have the issue. When the "Save as Adobe PDF" button is clicked, it is calling the BeforeClose event in my add-in and then when I go back to the workbook the ribbon is gone and all custom right-click functions are gone. The debugger remains open, however. The "Save as Adobe PDF" is part of the Acrobat PDFMaker add-in and I don't want to have to tell users to avoid using it.

I expect that my add-in does not shutdown when the "Save as Adobe PDF" button is clicked. As mentioned, I even have this issue with a base document-level add-in with almost zero changes (other than adding a simple ribbon).

Comment: can you post your code on the BeforeClose event?

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be possible to somehow catch the name of the calling 3rd party add-in and not run any code on your event. I suspect that all add-ins who subscribe to the event will be called in sequence, and it sounds like yours is 2nd or further down the list.

Comment: @kowieleroux, I have a blank BeforeClose event since I just wanted to check when it was closing. I tried setting Cancel = true, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: So if you remove the BeforeClose event subscription from your code, does it still exhibit the same issue?

Comment: I just tried removing the BeforeClose event subscription and it is still removing the ribbon.

Comment: Are you able to unload/disable other Add-ins through the COM Add-ins dialog box in the Excel interface? If yes, try turning the suspect add-ins off, one-by-one until you're sure which it is (if any). If the add-in can be turned off here, it can also be done in code...